# How to put two plots in one figure, vertically?

Tags: graphics, floats, plot, wrapfigure

I have two histograms. Together they tell one story, so I want to put them in one figure. I want to stick to one column format, therefore I want them vertically. How can I do that?

I've only seen answers on how to put them next to each other horizentally.

EDIT: turns out that I can simply repeat \includegraphics twice and that's it!!
Okay, so how can I put sub-label for each one? like (a) and (b) ?? so that I can talk about them in the caption?

Comment: You may be interested in the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, an alternative would be [`subfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) (personally, I usually use `subcaption`, so I can't really tell you which is better). Stay clear of the obsolete `subfigure` package that might be advertised in older blog posts or outdated templates.

Comment: @moewe Got it. Thanks!